# CSS to SCSS - How to change media queries

Tags: css, sass

In my angular project, I switched from using **CSS** to **SCSS**, but I have a problem with the existing media queries.

In **CSS** I had:

```
/* Safari 10.1+ (which is the latest version of Safari at this time) */
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {
   .safari_only { 
       color:#0000FF; 
       background-color:#CCCCCC; 
   }
}}
```

How can I change this code to **SCSS**? 
**SCSS** building gives me this error:

> Media feature required in media query expression

Comment: CSS seems to be incorrect. Please check the nested media query.

Comment: this was working on .css

Comment: It sure was working but syntatically it is incorrect. There are a lot of things browsers will try and fix for you to get best user experience but that doesn't mean your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.safari_only {
  @media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    @media {
      color: #00F;
      background-color: #CCC
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because your CSS is not correct. You have used an empty nested media tag. I tried converting it using this tool and it threw an error:
http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It might work in ios but syntactically it is incorrect. SASS will only get compiled if you are using a syntactically valid CSS. It has got nothing to do with browsers.